# Android. MIDI. Playing first N notes

Tags: android, midi

I'm writing an app, that plays MIDI files. Is there any chance to play only N first notes (say 5) of MIDI file?

Thanks in advance!

Code example snippets would be great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course it's possible. It'd be a lot easier to find a library to do it though, try something like this:

https://code.google.com/p/android-midi-lib/

If that doesn't do it, google midi file manipulation library java or something like that, you'll find something.

Edit: Take a look at this, it's newer and more relevant 
[Android 6.0 (Marshmallow): How to play midi notes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36193250/android-6-0-marshmallow-how-to-play-midi-notes)

Comment: I used this library but I am not getting how to play first note separately, second separately and so on..?

Comment: Try checking out the answer to the question I linked, seems like a much easier way of doing it.