# android - play a sound(note) for a certain duration

Tags: android, audio

I have an application that so far recognizes some notes and I need to play them, but I need them in different duration.

I was thinking of having some mp3s with the notes, but I haven't found a way to play them a specific duration.

Can you help me with a solution for this issue?

Comment: You could [play notes with the internal synthesizer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36193250/android-6-0-marshmallow-how-to-play-midi-notes/). It would be a quite convenient way to play notes at a specific pitch for a specific duration if you have/can get a basic understanding of MIDI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Timer Task for this work. It executes your code for specific limit of time.